# Moving data from RDS -> S3 using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm trying to load an entire table from a MySQL Database (RDS) to S3, through AWS Glue.

I have already configured the RDS connection and created the Glue table with a crawler.

Now I have to perform a ETL Job to load the table from RDS to S3. However, after correctly following the AWS documentation procedure, inside the S3 directory, I find some files, but none of these is a JSON file (with headers and data) as I requested in Glue's Job.

Where am I wrong?

Thank you.